# Perl doubts - regarding usage of word boundary and need for escaping the special character in back reference syntax:

Tags: regex, perl

In Perl, I could do the below without word boundary

```
$_ =~ /\b[A-Z]\S*/;
```

as

```
$_ =~ /[A-Z]\S*/;
```

gives the same result for the input "*A home For a Person*".

Still in what circumstances word boundary '**`\b`**' has significance?

---

Also, when I use the back-reference of type **`$1`**, **`$2`** ... etc., then the special character '**`@`**' needs to be escaped as '**`\@`**'

```
echo gmail.in@x1 | perl -pe 's/(\S+)@(.*)/$2\@$1/'    # Ans: x1@gmail.in
```

But when I use the backreference of this version, **`\1`** or **`\2`** .. etc., then I do not need to escape the '**`@`**' character in the replacement part:

```
echo gmail.in@x1 | perl -pe 's/(\S+)@(.*)/\2@\1/'   # Ans: x1@gmail.in
```

Why this behavior?

Comment: That's two questions. They are otherwise both reasonable, could you ask them separately?

Comment: Yes, I clubbed those as they are just one line questions, so did not want to bump up the pages :)

Answer (score 1):

In your first question, the "result" you speak of is merely that they can both fail or succeed. You are not actually capturing a string, so your question is somewhat moot. However, the word boundary will prevent partial matching, for example:

```
'foobar' =~ /\b(bar)/;    # will not match
'foobar' =~ /(bar)/;      # will match
```

The word boundary is a zero-width assertion that matches the space between a word character and a non-word character, i.e. a boundary around a word.

Your second question is simply that `@$1` is the dereferencing of a reference, and `@\1` is not. If you store an array reference in a scalar variable, and want to dereference it to access the original array, you place an `@` sign in front of it, like so:

```
my @array = (1, 2, 3);
my $aref  = \@array;
my @new   = @$aref;      # @new now contains 1,2,3
```

That being said, using `\1` is not recommended. If you turn warnings on, your statement will give the following warning:

```
\1 better written as $1 at -e line 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets start from the second one. In Perl `@` is a special character for Array. Please take a look at this example:

```
my @a = qw(a c v);  # array
my $ref = \@a;      # i am taking reference of the array
print @$ref;        # now using @ sign i am taking out the array from reference
```

Another example:

```
my $str = "abc";   # a random string
$str =~ /(.)/;     # matching a character into $1
print "ok @$1";    # output: ok
print "ok \@$1";   # output: ok @a
```

For the above example the first output is only `ok`. Because it considered `$1` as array reference as I have used `@` just before this. So `@$1` has an empty array. For the second output it came up with `ok @a` because I have escaped the `\@` and `$1` has `a` in it from the previous regex match.

Now come to the first question. I am changing the input string a bit here.

```
my $str = 'aaA home For a Person';
## case-1
if ($str =~ /(\b[A-Z]\S*)/) {
    print "$1";    ## output: For
}
## case-2    
if ($str =~ /([A-Z]\S*)/) {
    print "$1";    ## output: A
}
```

You have seen the output are different here. `\b` defines for any non word(not in `\w`) character. So in the first example `A` has `aa` before it. And the regex didn't pick the `A` this time and went for the next capital letter `F` as it has space before it(a non word character).